# How do I add missing dictionaries for aspell?

Tags: linux, aspell

Aspell version:

```
$ aspell -v
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6)
```

Dump dict yields no results:

```
$ aspell dump dicts
```

First noticed the problem when I did this, was originally working on web server, but someone updated something and it hasn't worked since:

```
$ aspell check temp_test_file.txt
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
```

What's the proper way of installing the required dictionaries? I believe we're running this on CentOS.

And also, /usr/lib/aspell-0.60 does not contain the required dictionaries (provided that they're supposed to be saved there).

data-dir: /usr/lib/aspell-0.60

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you've installed `pspell`/`aspell` via a package channel, the dictionaries may be available in another package. On CentOS 6 using default yum repositories, English dictionaries are in package `aspell-en`.

Comment: I can confirm this answer is also relevant on CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 (tested both).  I should then be valid for aspell on OEL (as derived from centos) and scientific (derived from RHEL).

Comment: I had to get the epel repo before this worked. Detailed here: https://www.theshell.guru/install-aspell-centos-7-2/

Comment: I also use CentOS 7.9. I found in the error message that he ws looking for de.dat

```
/usr/bin/aspell --lang=de --encoding=utf-8 create master /home/MYUSER/.recoll/aspdict.de.rws
Fehler: The language "de" is not known. Der Grund ist wahrscheinlich: the file "/usr/lib64/aspell-0.60/de.dat" can not be opened for reading.
```
I had a look, there was not *.dat file. After installing aspell-en there were the english files. No package aspell-de available. So this needs manual installation.

You can get dictionaries from  ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html .

Comment: answer is relevant to manjaro also.

Answer (score 7):

Download dictionaries from here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/
Unzip it and do,

```
    ./configure
    make 
    make install
```

All the instructions are in README. This Makefile will find the correct locations that these dictionaries should go to.

Comment: To add dictionaries in any language go to https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html
You really need to

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem on Fedora 22. I solved it by installing `aspell-en.x86_64`package.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had file permission errors with the `make install` step (as per the README instructions from the download above) and couldn't `chmod` the /sw/share/aspell/ directory. Running `sudo make install` got around the problem.

Hope that saves someone a headache!

Answer (score -1):

On macOS, my problem (as per usual) was that I installed it via some method other than Homebrew (`brew install aspell` and/or `brew cask install cocoaspell`).

Answer (score -2):

You need to install `en-aspell`. In FreeBSD:

`pkg install en-aspell`

Comment: OP's question was asking how to do this on Linux, not FreeBSD....

Comment: I agree. The package might have a completely different name in Linux, and the name could even vary between Linux distros.